# Background image stretch full screen inside container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a background image stretch to full width. Here is my markup

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3><a href="#" class="logo" >The Sound <span class="fa fa-volume-off" style="color:#EF4836;"></span>linic</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="vspace2"></div>
      <nav class="navbar text-center" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span style="color:#555;" class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
          </button>
       </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="fattify" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="fattify" href="#">Studio</a></li>
            <li><a class="fattify" href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li><a class="fattify" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>

    <div class="first-main">
      <div class="text-center">
        Whatever I write here
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I am using bootstrap. The background image inside the `first-main` class does not stretch to full screen width. How can I do that ?

Here is the extra css part:

```
.first-main{
    border-top: 5px solid #555;
    background : url('../../studio-1.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size :100% auto;
    width : 100% ;
    height: 800px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t1gg3g1/)

Comment: Put a demo, you have so much html code and only 1 element has css here.

Comment: I tried something here and the image is occupying 100% of the width. You should check if you have any class conflicting... http://jsfiddle.net/vfdhqvrk/

Comment: Please see my fiddle

Comment: What I meant was, How can I make it stretch full screen inside a container ? If you see there are  white spaces left and right of the image

Comment: I replied the question saying what i would do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your .container has margin: 0 15px;

Basically you can use margin: 0 -15px on the container of the image. Isn't the best solution, as you know. For this layouts, when you work with different widths, is better don't define a default to the layout, put a margin inside each element instead all the document. You'll avoid so many problems in the future.

---

*But as i said.*.. You can use margin to "align" this.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8t1gg3g1/5/

Basically what you need to do is put some properties inside the container of the image.

```
.first-main{
    border-top: 5px solid #555;
    background : url(http://votemenot.com/upload/398/3980.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size :100% auto;
    width : 100% ;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

The content-box is for remove the border-box default of the bootstrap, that makes each element don't increase width when you use padding, as you probably know.

---

But i recommend you reajust your container to have no problems in the future.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8t1gg3g1/8/

Comment: Also I guess I was missing the 'row' class and I should be replacing container with container-fluid for full width ?

Comment: When you work with elements the occupies all the screen, you only need to put width: 100%, when you work with elements that use a specific width, you work with a default value created by a element. See: http://jsfiddle.net/7obv8a5e/

Comment: Don't forget to put a @media screen to transform the `.align` into a element with width: 100% to be ajusted to responsive :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should try in CSS:

```
background-size:cover;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t1gg3g1/1/)